# Replacing #(..) with a already defined variable value in karate

Tags: spring-boot, karate

Works:

```
* def abc = "hello"
* def jsonmap = {a:  "#(abc)"}
* print jsonmap
```

Doesnot Work:

```
* def jsonmap = {a:  "#(abc)"}    
* def abc = "hello"
* print jsonmap
```

Any suggestion on how to replace "#(ABC)" with ABC in jsonmap in 2nd case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* jsonmap.a = 'hello'
```

Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#js-for-json